# create Android inner Clock

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Lately im trying to implement a new clock witch does not depend from device clock. When activity start i get time from my server and use AsyncTask to increase time with 1 each second. in this activity i have other task, my problem is when i execute an other task the first task that i use for my clock freezes until that other task is finished. so if my second task needs 2 second to finish my clock is 2 second behind and so on. What can i do to play multiply task indipendent from each other within an activity?

Comment: Are you starting both AsyncTasks from onCreate() ? Can you show some sniplet as to how you are doing it. It would make easier to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was, task in android by default are executed one after an other not in parallel.

To execute a task in parallel write

```
Runnable runclock = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        new runclock().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
};
```

or to execute in series write

```
Runnable runclock = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        new runclock().execute("");
    }
};
```

Thank You